# Php list to tabular view

Tags: php, html

Hello I am doing a shopping store project in Php.I am trying to display my products just like a shopping cart page.I did it in a list view which shows all products one below another in vertical format.I had thoughts to show in a tabular format with 4-5 products on each row as in real world shopping websites but I am getting nowhere.
my code is:

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM burgers ORDER BY id';
$result = $db->query($sql);
$output = '<ul>';
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $output .= '<li>"'.$row['title'].'" made by </br> '.$row['chef'].': Rs '.$row['price'].'<img src="images/'.$row['image'].'" width="100" height="100" /><br />';
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $output .= '<a href="cart.php?action=add&id='.$row['id'].'">Add to cart</a></li>';
    }
    else {
        $output .= '<a href="login.php">Login</a></li>';
    }
}
$output .= '</ul>';
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: If you want all the items to be listed like a table, having the same type of elements at the same horizontal position, better use a table.

Comment: I tried it its showing some nonsense output or I am not able to do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show it in tabular format you can just use table. It is created for things like this. Just do something like this:

```
$output = '<table><tr>';
$products_per_row = 5;
$i = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $i++;
    $output .= '<td>"'.$row['title'].'" made by </br> '.$row['chef'].': Rs '.$row['price'].'<img src="images/'.$row['image'].'" width="100" height="100" /><br />';
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $output .= '<a href="cart.php?action=add&id='.$row['id'].'">Add to cart</a></td>';
    }
    else {
        $output .= '<a href="login.php">Login</a></td>';
    }
    if ($i == $products_per_row) { $output .= '</tr><tr>'; $i = 0; }
}
$output .= '</tr></table>';
```

If you want to use li you can fix it's width, use css for this (li { width: x px; } ), where x is row (ul's container) width divided by number of columns. Eg if you want 5 products per row, and your container above ul (and ul) has 1000px width, just do li with 200px. Don't forget about padding and margins.

Comment: I modifed code - in last if you should set $i = 0. You'll see that :)